# Android AppWidget + android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"

Tags: android, android-activity, widget

I want my app to show a login-screen every time it is opened. With `android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"` everything works fine. But there is a bug which is happening only if the phone was shutdown and the app was first started with the widget.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, StartActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
[....]
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_onebyone)
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget, pendingIntent);
```

This code should start my mainactivity. At first start is does. But ending the app with HOME and restart it with the widget causes my app to not start with my startactivity but with another activity of my app without showing the loginscreen.
What can I do to fix it. 
I've tried

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

But it does not work. All I want is to (re)-start the StartActivity-Intent like in `startActivity(..)` but I found no option to give my Widget an OnClickListener which starts a "normal" Activity.

Best regards,

Till

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding the Flag to the intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, StartActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
[....]
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_onebyone)
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget, pendingIntent);
```

**Intent API**

[setFlags(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setFlags%28int%29)

[FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)

Comment: Thanks, due to API Lvl 7 I used `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` but it seems to work fine.